# Should an angularjs $resource be wrapped in a factory? Why not service?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service, angular-resource, angular-services, angularjs-factory

why a `$resource` should be used by `.factory`? and why `.service` is a wrong way?

e.g.

```
app.factory('Notes', ['$resource', function($resource) {
return $resource('/notes/:id', null,
    {
        'update': { method:'PUT' }
    });
}]);
```

why is it wrong?

```
app.service('Notes', ['$resource', function($resource) {
return $resource('/notes/:id', null,
    {
        'update': { method:'PUT' }
    });
}]);
```

Comment: The second one would work fine, but only because JavaScript has this weird feature of allowing a constructor function to return an object, instead of just initializing `this`and returning it. Since you don't really won't to construct an object, but instead want to return one, a factory make more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both are singletons, but `services` are instantiated using the `new` keyword.
You won't be able to access the static class methods of `$resource` if you're going to use `service` which, depending on your application may be better.

In other words you won't be able to use:

```
Notes.query({ ... });
Notes.create({ ... });
```

and other class function variants. Only instance methods such as:

```
note.$get()
note.$save()
note.$update()
```

Comment: This is not exactly true. It may not be the best thing to do, but it is possible to get static methods with `Notes.prototype.constructor.query`.

Comment: OP asked why it was a bad practice - your workaround is a good example why.